# StakeOut: Find Optimal Expectation Using Recursion

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I was recently presented with a coding assignment by a startup I was interviewing with.  They gave me the following problem and asked for a solution:

> Congratulations! You are the new elite hacker in a group of villainous
>   ne'er-do-wells.
>
> Luckily this group is more saavy than your last band of ruffians, and
>   they are looking to software (and you) to improve their take. The con
>   man for the team, has gone door-to-door down each street posing as a
>   termite inspector so he could covertly total the valuable goods in
>   each house. Normally the gang would just rob all the valuable homes,
>   but there's a catch! Whenever a house is robbed in this wealthy
>   neighborhood, the police watch it and the neighboring houses for
>   months.
>
> So the gang can't simply rob all the homes, and if they choose to rob
>   one, they can no longer rob the house on either side of it.
>
> The ringleader wants to know what houses he should rob to maximize the
>   team's profit, and he wants to know now. Write a function that takes
>   in an array of positive integers (home values) and returns the maximum
>   expected value of robbing that street.
>
> For example:
>
> [ 20, 10, 50, 5, 1 ] should return $71, as robbing the first, third,
>   and fifth houses is optimal [ 20, x, 50, x, 1 ]
>
> [ 20, 50, 10, 1, 5 ] should return $55, as robbing the second and
>   fifth houses is optimal [ x, 50, x, x, 5 ]

Basically, you can only sum the values of alternative houses because if a house is robbed, the houses immediately before and after it cannot be robbed, due to heavy security in the street.

I wrote a solution using recursion and presented it to them.  
I presented a solution which accounted for all cases except for the following:

> [2, 3, 2], for which the returned answer was 3, instead of 4.

They told me to fix the bug.  Since, it was the only case for which the algorithm didn't work, I used the following code to fix the problem (written in JavaScript):

```
// The recursive alrogithm doesn't account for arrays of length 3.
    if(array.length === 3) {
        if(array[0] + array[2] > array[1]) {
            return 'Optimal expectation of robbing street: ' + String(array[0] + array[2]);
        } else{
            return 'Optimal expectation of robbing street: ' + String(array[1]);
        }
    }
```

So the complete final solution is as follows (with the above snippet of code included):

```
    // Global variable for expectation:
    var expectation = 0;

    function optimalExpectation(array) {
        // 'array' contains the home values

        // The recursive alrogithm doesn't account for arrays of length 3.
        if(array.length === 3) {
            if(array[0] + array[2] > array[1]) {
                return 'Optimal expectation of robbing street: ' + String(array[0] + array[2]);
            } else{
                return 'Optimal expectation of robbing street: ' + String(array[1]);
            }
        }
        // Base case for recursion:
        if(array.sum() === 0) {
                return 'Optimal expectation of robbing street: ' + String(expectation);
        } else{
            expectation += array.max();
            var maxIndex = array.indexOf(array.max());
            // Recursive call:
            return optimalExpectation(injectZeros(array, maxIndex));
        }
    }

    //===============================================================================
    // Protypal methods for maximum & sum:
    // All array objects inherit these methods from the Array prototype:

    Array.prototype.max = function(){
        if(this.length === 1){
            return this[0];
        } else if(this.length === 0){
            return null;
        }
        var maximum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            if(maximum < Math.max(this[i], this[i + 1])){
                maximum = Math.max(this[i], this[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        return maximum;
    };

    Array.prototype.sum = function(){
        var sum = 0;
        this.forEach(function(el){
            sum += el;
        });
        return sum;
    };

    // Function to replace maximum values, already accounted for, with zeroes:
    function injectZeros(array, index){
        if(array.length > 0){
            if(index < array.length - 1)
                array[index + 1] = 0;
            if(index > 0)
                array[index - 1] = 0;
        }
        array[index] = 0;
        return array;
    }

    //==================================================================================


    console.log(optimalExpectation([2, 3, 2]));  // correctly returns 4, instead of 3
```

I was rejected after I submitted the above solution.  They didn't reject me after my initial solution (they definitely could have).  They wanted me to explain my thought process and how I fixed the bug.

I would appreciate any input on where I might have gone wrong.  Is there a way to improve my algorithm?  Is my code well organized?  Is this the right approach?  If you are a professional developer who has knowledge of how hiring decisions are made in startups, could you elaborate on what might have lead the team to reject me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a hiring manager. But a quick inspection says that you only picked biggest houses as much as you could. The problem is conceptual, and you swept it under the rug instead of fixing your algorithm (the issue would also present itself with `[2, 3, 2, 0.5]`, as you pick `3` then `0.5`, instead of the optimal `2` and `2` - there is nothing special about length 3). The correct solution would at least use backtracking to explore if picking different elements would have made more profit, rather than greedily picking the local maximum without regard to context. It is sufficient to inspect the maximum and the neighbours at each step.

```js
var values = [2, 3, 2, 0.5];

function rob(values) {
  if (values.every(function(e) { return e === null })) return [];
  var len = values.length;
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
  var subMax = -Infinity;
  var subArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (values[i] !== null && (values[i - 1] === max || values[i] === max || values[i + 1] === max)) {
      nextValues = values.slice();
      nextValues[i] = null;
      if (i > 0) nextValues[i - 1] = null;
      if (i < len - 1) nextValues[i + 1] = null;
      var subResult = rob(nextValues);
      var subSum = subResult.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0) + values[i];
      if (subSum > subMax) {
        subArray = subResult;
        subArray.push(values[i]);
        subMax = subSum;
      }
    }
  }
  return subArray;
};

alert(rob(values));
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  The very first solution I wrote for this problem (an iterative one) works for all cases.  I then, in an attempt to impress the developer team, tried recursion and came up with the above "solution" (which was influenced by the solution in an online post by someone else to the same problem).  How foolish of me to not submit the solution I came up with by myself!  This has been a learning experience for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should go a watch Professor Roughgarden's lecture about Weighted Independent Set in Path Graphs, https://class.coursera.org/algo2-2012-001/lecture/83. It uses Dynamic Programming to solve the interview question. The solution is fairly trivial. You can do it using either recursion or iterations.

Comment: That lecture explained the concepts of the maximum independent set very well.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

```
function computeRob (arr, index, canRob) {
    if(arr.length == index){
        return 0;
    }

    if (canRob == true) {
        var withRob = arr[index] + computeRob(arr, index + 1, false);
        var withoutRob = computeRob(arr, index + 1, true);
        return Math.max(withRob, withoutRob)
    } else {
        return withoutRob = computeRob(arr, index + 1, true);
    }
}

console.log(computeRob([4,3,8,9,2],0,true));
```